Loss of 2%to 3% of disk space after 2 days of idle time
Ubuntu 22.04.5 VM guest hosted by Windows 11 Home/ VirtualBox configuration. The VM has lost between 2% to 3% of disk space on the root partition after just two days of basically sitting idle. Only the weather app Meteo and the System Monitor are running.
Is there a tool that can examine the desktop and execute some type of disk cleanup in order to restore space back to the partition?

This question is similar to: What's a command line way to find large files/directories to remove and free up space? and Very large log files, what should I do?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
